# C# - Adding to an existing (generated) constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, multiple-constructors

I have a constructor that is in generated code.  I don't want to change the generated code (cause it would get overwritten when I regenerate), but I need to add some functionality to the constructor.

Here is some example code:

```
// Generated file
public partial class MyGeneratedClass
{
   public MyGeneratedClass() 
   {
      Does some generated stuff
   }
}
```

The only solution I can come up with is this:

```
// My hand made file
public partial class MyGeneratedClass
{
   public MyGeneratedClass(bool useOtherConstructor):this()
   {
      do my added functinallity
   }
}
```

I am fairly sure this will work, but I then have a lame unused param to my constructors and I have to go change them all.  Is there a better way?  If not that is fine, but I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C# 3 and can change the generator, you can use [*partial methods*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx):

```
// MyGeneratedClass.Generated.cs
public partial class MyGeneratedClass
{
   public MyGeneratedClass() 
   {
      // Does some generated stuff
      OnConstructorEnd();
   }

   partial void OnConstructorEnd();
}

// MyGeneratedClass.cs
public partial class MyGeneratedClass
{
   partial void OnConstructorEnd()
   {
      // Do stuff here
   }
}
```

Comment: Alas, this is code generated from a WSDL.  I have no idea how to change that generator.

Comment: Darn... if you can't change the generator, you can't do a lot, unfortunately. You could derive a new class from the generated one, but I tend to view that as a bit of an abuse of inheritance. You can add other constructors of course - but if you don't *need* any extra parameters, it's a bit of a pain. How about adding a static method which calls the constructor and then calls something else?

Answer (score 1):

Would your environment allow you to inherit from MyGeneratedClass rather than have it as a partial class. You could then override the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't change the generator output, unfortunately, your options are a bit limited, and not ideal considering what you're looking for. They are:

- Inherit from the generated class. The child class will implicitly call the parent's construtor.
- Use a static method as an initializer